# Including external Js file ( not library ) in Angular2

Tags: angular, import

I am new to Angular2. I have a constant.js files having some constant vars defined in it as below :

`CONST = {
  TITLE:'Page Title'
}`...

I want to use this TITLE in my component's template like :

 `<label>{{CONST.TITLE}}</label>`

or as in underscore :

`<%=CONST.TITLE %>`.

I have underscore working.

Can anyone guide me the way to do using either underscore or interpolation method in the Angular app

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you developing Angular 2 in Typescript? Not sure on your scenario but can this file be just a TS file, then you may import it.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your component 'declare var CONST: any' this is the quick way to do it.

https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/01/complex-typescript-definitions-made-easy/